# Custom servlet filter not working in Tomcat run as a service

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, servlet-filters

I have a servlet filter declared in web xml(inside war file). This works fine if tomcat (7.0.75) is run using startup.bat but if tomcat is run as a windows service it fails to launch without any errors in logs. If I remove this filter everything works fine regardless if it is service or bat.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.customFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.localhost</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.unsecure.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.client.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-client</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.krb5.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>krb5.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>login.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.username</param-name>
        <param-value>bfldap</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.password</param-name>
        <param-value>!user</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.server.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-server</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.prompt.ntlm</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.logger.level</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```